# 2 Swiper.js in one page

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I want to make 2 different sliders on the same page on my django site. When creating the second slider, all the settings of the first slider are changed to the settings of the second one. The options that I pass to the class instance are changed. How to fix it?

html:

```
<div class="carousel">
            {% if server.carousel.count == 1 %}
                {% for image in server.carousel.all %}
                    <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" class="slider_image" alt="slider_image">
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
            <div class="swiper-container slider1">
                
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    {% for image in server.carousel.all %}
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="image-slider__image">
                                <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" class="slider_slide-image" alt="slider_image">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
                
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
<div class="small-container server-detail__screenshots">    
                <div class="swiper-container slider2">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        {% for photo in server.screenshots.all %}
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="image-slider__image">
                                    <img src="{{ photo.image.url }}" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>

                    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                 </div>
            </div>
```

js:

```
const swiper1 = new Swiper('.slider1',{
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
    grabCursor: true,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 1500,
    },
})

const swiper2 = new Swiper('.slider2',{
        navigation: {
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        }
})
```